# Return a N by N two dimensional array from function

Tags: rust

I have a test

```
fn test_foo() {
    let a = foo();
    let b: [[u8; 4]; 4] = 
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4], 
        [3, 4, 1, 2],
        [2, 3, 4, 1], 
        [4, 1, 2, 3]
    ];
    assert_eq!(a, b);
}
```

The code for this, currently, is

```
pub fn foo() -> [[u8; ?]; ?] {
let x: [[u8; 4]; 4] = 
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4], 
        [3, 4, 1, 2],
        [2, 3, 4, 1], 
        [4, 1, 2, 3]
    ];
    x
}
```

Where I have placed the two question marks I don't want to replace them with `4` because I will be calling some other code in this method that could give me a 6 by 6 array or a 20 by 20 array.  How do I say that this function returns a two dimensional array but I don't know what size it will be?

Comment: I don't think you can. Size of return type must be known at compile time.

Comment: You could return Vec<Vec<>>, obviously, or a Box<[[]]>, but for the Box you'd still have to know the dimensions. The constraint that the inner and outer sizes are the same doesn't really matter - the fact that they can change does

Comment: @Codebling `Box<[[]]>` isn't valid, where would the inner slices be stored? Maybe you meant `Box<[Box<[]>]>`? In any case a better layout would be `Vec<T>` or `Box<[T]>` with a length of `N^2`, which results in the same layout as arrays would be. If you need to ensure it's actually square, wrap it in a newtype that upholds that property.